# How to find corresponding values in columns using TCL

Tags: tcl

I'm a regular matlab user who needs to do some processing in TCL. I have no experience with tcl so up to now what I have done is by searching on google.

Please pardon novice ways...

I have data in column A and B which is imported via file Data_1, I would like to get the corresponding values from column B for two numbers in column A e.g.

when A is 0.1 then B is 9 and when A is 0.3 then B is 21, store 9 & 21 in variable for later use

I'd like to open another file Data_2, which has two columns C and D.

I'd like to take all the numbers of column D that fall between Column 9 and 21 (positive numbers) in Column C and average it and put it in a variable for later use.

I've started with first trying to find corresponding values for 0.1 and 0.3, and that is where I am stuck.

I can (I think) find 0.1 and 0.3 but don't know how to get the corresponding values from column B

And then proceed ahead with the second part.

Please help.

```
     Data_1                         Data__2
Column A    Column B        Column C    Column D
0           0               180         14.5
0.01        1.5             162         13.05
0.02        3               144         11.6
0.03        4.5             126         10.15
0.04        6               108         8.7
0.05        7.5             90          7.25
0.1         9               72          5.8
0.125       10.5            54          4.35
0.15        12              20          2.9
0.175       13.5            10          1.45
0.2         15              0           0
0.225       16.5            -10         -1.45
0.25        18              -20         -2.9
0.275       19.5            -54         -4.35
0.3         21              -72         -5.8
0.325       22.5            -90         -7.25
0.35        24              -108        -8.7
0.0.375     25.5            -126        -10.15
0.4         27              -144        -11.6
0.425       28.5            -162        -13.05
0.45        30              -180        -14.5
```

```
# Open files for reading
set input1 [open "Data_1.dat" r]
set input2 [open "Data_2.dat" r]

#read file
set file_data [read $input1]
#close file
close $input1

#split into lines
set data [split $file_data "\n"]
foreach line $data {

set val1 [lsearch -inline $line 0.1]
set val2 [lsearch -inline $line 0.3]

puts $val1
puts $val2
}
```

Comment: The best place to start learning Tcl is the [Tcl tutorial](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcltutorial/html/tcltutorial.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd write this:

```
set min_key 0.1 
set max_key 0.3

set fid [open Data_1.dat r]
while {[gets $fid line] != -1} {
    lassign $line a b
    if {$a == $min_key} {
        set min $b
    }
    if {$a == $max_key} {
        set max $b
    }
}
close $fid

set fid [open Data_2.dat r]
while {[gets $fid line] != -1} {
    lassign $line c d
    if {$min <= $d && $d <= $max} {
        lappend values $c
    }
}
close $fid

puts [join $values \n]
```

This outputs

```
180
162
144
126
```

Notes:

- use a `while` loop to iterate over the lines of a file.
- `lassign` assigns values of a list to variables

Comment: Thank you Glenn, your example does exactly as I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite follow all of the if/else logic in your post, but there are several ways you can process the files. From your example, you can store the A and B columns as two separate lists.

```
set acol [list]
set bcol [list]
set data [split $file_data "\n"]
foreach line $data {
    lappend acol [lindex $line 0]
    lappend bcol [lindex $line 1]
}

# Find the first column A value that is 0.1.
set index [lsearch -real $acol 0.1]

# Get the corresponding B value.
puts "b value: [lindex $bcol $index]"
```

You can probably also just simplify the foreach-loop to this, without splitting the file data into lines.

```
foreach {val1 val2} $file_data {
    lappend acol $val1
    lappend bcol $val2
}
```